# Magento 2.2.6 : Shipment creation using REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, magento2.2.6, webapi

Unable to create shipment in Magento 2.2.6

I am using the following source code like this in postman

> https://test.com/rest/V1/shipment

```
{ "entity" : { "order_id" : 70, "items" : [{ "order_item_id" : 94, "qty" : 1 } ], "tracks" : [{ "carrierCode" : "UPS", "order_id" : 70, "title" : "ground", "trackNumber" : "12345678", "parentId" : 1001 } ] } }
```

Thanks

Comment: this json reponse issue, try with without json format.

Comment: how can i revert it

Comment: @shivashankarm is it working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your track array field format is wrong. Please try this below :

```
{  
   "entity":{  
      "order_id":70,
      "items":[  
         {  
            "order_item_id":94,
            "qty":1
         }
      ],
      "tracks":[  
         {  
            "carrier_code":"UPS",
            "order_id":70,
            "title":"ground",
            "track_number":"12345678",
            "parent_id":1001
         }
      ]
    ],
   }
}
```

For more reference : [Click here](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/salesShipmentRepositoryV1/salesShipmentRepositoryV1SavePost)

---

**UPDATE :**

Go to this path `/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` and replace at line no 3036

```
case 'longtext':
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $value = json_encode($value);
    }
    $value  = (string)$value;
    if ($column['NULLABLE'] && $value == '') {
        $value = null;
    }
    break;
```

Comment: I have tried with above, answer iam getting  "message": "Could not save shipment" this error.

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Hi @Rohan the above fix is for magento2.2.6 version only right?

Comment: Yes.... You can use in any version. If this error will return.

Comment: for local system it's working fine without change any code

Comment: Okay. You can accept and upvote my answer. So, it's useful for other :)